# Why save file with original name is dangerous in an upload?

Tags: security, file-upload, asp-classic

Currently I'm working on a web project (Classic Asp) and I'm going to make an upload form.

 
Folklore says:

> "Don't use the real name to save the uploaded files"

.
What are the problems, dangers, from the security point of view ?

Comment: It's only dangerous if you expose your upload folder inside your webspace. When dealing with uploads I usually store them outside the webspace and use a config value stored in an #include file to reference it. That way it's not accessible to malicious upload of asp code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper directory permissions should stop most of this stuff but I suppose for file names a potential danger is that they could name it something like "../Default.asp" or "../Malware.asp" or some other malicious path attempting to overwrite files and/or have an executable script on your server.

If I'm using a single upload folder, I always save my users uploads with a GUID file name just because users aren't very original and you get name conflicts very often otherwise.

Comment: The filename looking like this: ../Default.asp.txt or just ../Default.asp?
How the name would used to cause some problem? Do you have some example?

Comment: Those were just examples, users could try any malicious path, could be ../../../anything.asp or any of a million other path filename combos.  Here's a site that talks about it some: [Link](http://www.developershome.com/wap/wapUpload/wap_upload.asp?page=security)